# Conditional expectation of balls in box problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Assume there are $5$ balls in a box, $X$ black balls and $5-X$ white balls. $X$ is distributed uniform in {0,1,2,3,4,5}. We take a ball out of it, record the color, and put it back in the box, repeat 10 times, and record the number of black balls as random variable $Y$. Now what is $E(X|Y)$?

I know we can use the definition of conditional expect value and calculat it step by step. But it's a little complicated. Is there a more subtle way to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by $E(X|Y)$ exactly? There is no random variable $X|Y$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Maybe they just mean the conditional expectation... In that case, giving $E[X\mid Y]$ should be the same as giving $E[X\mid Y=k]$ for $k=0,\dots,10$

Comment: @hgmath so you fix $k$ ? To what value?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma for all the values that $Y$ could take, I guess that would be $k=0,\dots,10$?

Comment: @hgmath Wouldn't $k$ be from $0$ to $5$?

Comment: Note that the probability $P(Y=k \mid X= n)$ is easier to compute. So Bayes seems advised.

Comment: I know, but I can't figure out a way by using $P(Y|X)$ to solve this question easily..

Comment: @YiPing Is it supposed to be $E(X|Y)$ you need to find? It seems more likely to be $E(Y|X)$...

Comment: @SupremePickle It's $E(X|Y)$. It will be a trivial question if it's $E(Y|X)$.